# Horizontal scrollbar very big in ie7 and ie8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, width, scrollbar

If you look at [www.ijob.dk](http://www.ijob.dk) in IE7 and IE8, the horizontal scrollbar is MUCH larger than on ex: Firefox or IE9 (Don't even think the scrollbar shows in ie9) - Can't seem to figure out that is causing the big space at the right, since the horizontal scrolling is so large?

Comment: By the way, it's on a 1024 resolution!

Comment: Dont you get a vertical scrollbar?

Comment: WOOP, i ment a horisontal scrollbar - DOH! :)

Comment: Looks the same here in IE7 and SeaMonkey; no absurdly large scrollbars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment i understand now that you meant the horizontal scrollbar, just add this to your CSS to hide it:

```
html {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

There is some renegade element that is creating that extra few pixels of horizontal space that needs to be checked, but i think it is ok to just hide it, since your design is top-bottom.